# Is it possible to use a django filter on the result of a templatetag?

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I have a template tag which returns datetime objects converted to the user's timezone. To format it, I'd prefer the builtin filter "date" to format it.
Is it possible to use a filter on the result of a template tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if course you can. Filters are just functions that can be imported. Import the filter function you need from django.template.defaultfilters and pass your arguments to it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had tried it and it didn't work. I did "{% convert_tz datetime timezone %}|date format" and it gives an error. convert_tz returns a converted datetime.

Comment: You'll need to apply the filter function in your template tag Python code, not in the template itself. Alternatively, you could set a context variable in your template tag, and then apply the filter to that variable.

Comment: @Brandon, can you give a code example for your explanation?

Comment: What I meant was that the OP would need to leverage the `date` filter inside of his custom template tag. You can't pass the result of the template tag to the filter as indicated in the comment above.

Comment: @tsovarev's answer below is also a viable option. If you're going to write a custom tag, you may as well just use the date filter in the tag to keep the template dumb, just my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

You can wrap your custom templatetag with 'filter' templatetag:

```
{% filter date %}
    {% your_custom_tag %}
{% endfilter %}
```

More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter